# How can to invoke spring batch job while already running camel-jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-camel, spring-batch

I am working on one project where I am using camel-jpa for monitoring database for new entry. Once, poller returns some data, I need to call spring batch job and pass that data to it.

I have tried following way-

configure route to fetch data using jpa, then, covert these data into POJO, then
in bean, I am call spring batch job and pass these POJO to spring batch.

route configuration-

```
from("jpa:Sample?entityType=com.Sample&consumer.delay=600000&consumer.query=select s from com.Sample s&consumeDelete=false&consumeLockEntity=false&maximumResults=1")
.convertBodyTo(Sample.class)
.beanRef("myBean", "dataProcessing")
.log("${body}");
```

In myBean, I am accesing data using Exchange and calling spring batch job.

Here, execution get stopped with error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client)"

I am new to camel-jpa, please someone can help me out?